# Assets not working in angular5

Tags: assets, angular5

**in my app.component.html**
I have tried this
   `<img src="/assets/icon.png" >`
I have also tried
`<img src="assets/icon.png" >`
in my assets folder i've copied the icon.png
**in angular-cli.json**
       `"assets": ["assets", "favicon.ico"  ],`
 **and in index.html**
   `<base href="/">`
I run `ng serve` from the command line

**in chrome console**
 I'm getting this error
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 icon.png
 (Not Found)`

I run `ng build` 
the dist folder does not contain any assets it starts with index.html and ends with vendor.bundle.js.map

Comment: I have the same problem. it works in my mac, but in the git clone to my desktop, it does not work